# Twig: Displaying Stripe Customer Cards

Tags: php, twig, stripe-payments, slim

I am having some troubles displaying customer cards in Twig. I can do it PHP with this code:

```
$card = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($cu->cus_id)->sources->all(['object' => 'card']);

$i = 0;

foreach ($card["data"] as $cd) {

    echo $card["data"][$i]->brand . " - " . ucwords($card["data"][$i]->funding) . " Card: " . $card["data"][$i]->last4;
    if($i == 0){
        echo " (Default)";
    }
    echo "<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

But I need to output in a Twig template. I have tried the following:

```
 {% for data in cards|keys %}
     {{ card["data"][loop.index].last4 }}
 {% endfor %}
```

but that does not output anything at all.

I am using the Slim PHP Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert PHP to Twig easily.

I don't know how this pipe (`cards|keys`) is executed, but I'm sure its described in the official documentation [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation).

```twig
{% set i = 0 %}

{% for cd in card.data %}
    {{ cd.brand ~ ' - ' ~ cd.funding ~ ' Card: ' ~ cd.last4 }}

    {{ i == 0 ? ' (Default)' : '' }}
    <br />

    {% set i = i + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

It's not tested but should work.